# Can't get app to display cryptocurrency amount

Tags: iphone, swift, swift3, xcode8, ios11

From "**var myValue:[Double]...**" and "**var activeCurrency:Double = 0;**" to the third **pickerview code**, I am not sure what to do in order to fix the   "**self.myValues.append((Url as? Double)!)**" so that my app displays the currency amount. I have searched everywhere, and have no luck in finding anything. You are my last hope, please help. I'm still fairly new to coding, so I may not know the certain jargon.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

var myCurrency:[String] = []
var myValues:[Double] = []
var activeCurrency:Double = 0;

//OBJECTS
@IBOutlet weak var textbox: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var pickerView: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var output: UILabel!


//CREATING PICKER VIEW
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return myCurrency.count
}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return myCurrency[row]
}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    activeCurrency = myValues[row]
}

//BUTTON
@IBAction func action(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    if (textbox.text != "") {
    output.text = String(Double(textbox.text!)! * activeCurrency)
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //DATA GRABBING
    let url = URL(string: "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/all/coinlist")

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print ("ERROR")
        }
        else {
            if let content = data {
                do {
                    let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject

                    if let rates = myJson["Data"] as? NSDictionary {
                        for (Name, Url) in rates {
                            self.myCurrency.append((Name as? String)!)
                            self.myValues.append((Url as? Double)!)
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch {
                }
            }
        }
        if data != nil {
            DispatchQueue.main.async { // Correct
                self.pickerView.reloadAllComponents()
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}

   override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
       super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
       // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
   }
}
```

Comment: regarding to this line: `self.myValues.append((Url as? Double)!)`... how could a _URL_ be casted as _double_ in any possible universe? or what is `Url` actually?

Comment: Can you please post some sample JSON received?

Comment: I was watching a youtube video on how to make a currency convertor, but this video had nothing to do with cryptocurrency, so "double" or "no double" placed there, I have no idea what it even means, this universe, or the next. I tried looking but no success. The URL is apart of the code in the cryptocurrency api. This is the JSON api

Comment: BaseImageUrl = "https://www.cryptocompare.com";
    BaseLinkUrl = "https://www.cryptocompare.com";
    Data =     {
        007 =         {
            Algorithm = Scrypt;
            CoinName = "007 coin";
            FullName = "007 coin (007)";
            FullyPremined = 0;
            Id = 5294;
            ImageUrl = "/media/350595/007.png";
            Name = 007;
            PreMinedValue = "N/A";
            ProofType = PoW;
            SortOrder = 263;
            Sponsored = 0;

Comment: Here is the rest of it with the URL at the bottom...
            Symbol = 007;
            TotalCoinSupply = 989800;
            TotalCoinsFreeFloat = "N/A";
            Url = "/coins/007/overview";
        };

Comment: https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/all/coinlist